# Returning a reference of a vector object, good idea?

Tags: c++

I have a need for a 3d vector to store some tile objects, rather than putting a vector inside a vector inside a vector I tried this:

```
inside a struct
...
vector<sortTile3> data;
uint32_t width, length, height;

sortTile3& At(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) {
    return data[x * width + y * length + z];
}
...
```

Seems to work fine, also should be faster, i think, because instead of 3 memory fetches it would do 1 memory fetch and 4 calculations or 2 calculations if i can figure out how to do a fused multiply add.

Anyway, I remember reading something on this very site about returning references being bad. I can see why.. a lot of things can go wrong but shouldn't be the case with this one..or?

Comment: This highly depends on the environement. As long as you manage the lifetime of the struct the vector will survive. But this can become hard to maintain.

Comment: If your struct represents a container of things, it is perfectly fine to return references to the contained things.

Comment: Returning a reference to an object is only bad if the lifetime of the object is too short to be useful, unknown, or unclear. For container-like objects, none of these are problems.

Comment: I just did some performance testing, it appears that it is indeed faster, if only by a tiny sliver 499ms vs 515ms (over 1 billion iterations of assignment and fetches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine and usual. The problem with returning a reference concerns (mostly) function-local objects. To wit:

```
struct foo {
  int data;

  // this is fine
  int &ref1() {
    return data;
  }

  // this is NOT fine
  int &ref2() {
    int localdata;
    return localdata;
  }
}
```

The reason the latter is not fine is that `localdata` goes out of scope when `foo::ref2` is left, and then the returned reference will not refer to a valid object.

Generally, you have to take care to not keep references to objects longer than their lifetime, but there is nothing inherently wrong with returning a reference to a data member from a member function.

You may, for example, have noticed that `std::vector`'s `operator[]` returns a reference to its members; it is fine for you to do the same thing. You do, however, have to be careful not to store them longer than they remain valid. For example:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
int &r = v[0];
v.resize(20);

// r is no longer valid because v may have relocated its storage.
```

Note also that there are certain things that you can only achieve by returning a reference. If you want, for example, to be able to do

```
yourstruct.At(0, 1, 2).foo = bar;
```

and have the change stick, returning a copy will not be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a problem if the reference gets stored (and not just used temporarily). The reference will get invalidated when the `vector` reallocates memory or when items in the `vector` get moved around (`insert`), or when the `vector` gets deleted. If the `vector` is no longer modified after these references get stored, it will be safe.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector on iterator invalidation.

Comment: Isn't that the same case with pointers though? Somebody could hold on to  a dead pointer just the same.

Comment: I think for `std::vector`, references, pointers and iterators to elements have the same behavior.